# Google maps Geolocation API doesn't updates markers and circles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to update two circles on the map according to the user input of two locations. The circles update only the second time I hit the submit button and they are showing the location of the previous two locations entered. I guess the global markers are updated only at the end of the function but I can't see why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>map panel</title>

    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='img/favicon.ico'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

   <style>
      html, body {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding:0px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
      }


    </style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=geometry"></script>

<script>    

    var map;

    //tel aviv
    var distLatLng = {lat: 32.072369, lng: 34.783513};
    //Binyamina
    var distLatLng2 = {lat: 32.521128, lng: 34.945219};

    var distmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: distLatLng});
    var distmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: distLatLng2});


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var DistCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle({ strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', strokeOpacity: 0.9, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', fillOpacity: 0.10, map: map, center: distLatLng, radius: 30000});
    var DistCircle2 = new google.maps.Circle({ strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', strokeOpacity: 0.9, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', fillOpacity: 0.10, map: map, center: distLatLng2, radius: 30000});



    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;


    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      distmarker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
    })



    geocoder.geocode({'address': address2}, function(results2, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      distmarker2.setPosition(results2[0].geometry.location);

      } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
    })



    DistCircle1.setOptions({center: distmarker.getPosition()});
    DistCircle2.setOptions({center: distmarker2.getPosition()});
    DistCircle1.setMap(resultsMap);
    DistCircle2.setMap(resultsMap); 

    }


    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        minZoom: 9,
        maxZoom: 16,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.077, 34.644),
        <!--mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE-->
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);


    });

    }
    //end of initalize

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>



<section>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="searchpanel">



            <input id="address" type="textbox" value="tel aviv">
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
            <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="jerusalem">

    </div>


</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the returned results in the callback function when they are available.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xjz39mnw/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

//tel aviv
var distLatLng = {
  lat: 32.072369,
  lng: 34.783513
};
//Binyamina
var distLatLng2 = {
  lat: 32.521128,
  lng: 34.945219
};

var distmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: distLatLng
});
var distmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: distLatLng2
});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var DistCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  strokeOpacity: 0.9,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  fillOpacity: 0.10,
  map: map,
  center: distLatLng,
  radius: 30000
});
var DistCircle2 = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  strokeOpacity: 0.9,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  fillOpacity: 0.10,
  map: map,
  center: distLatLng2,
  radius: 30000
});

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      distmarker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      distmarker.setMap(map);
      bounds.extend(distmarker.getPosition());
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address2
      }, function(results2, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          distmarker2.setPosition(results2[0].geometry.location);
          distmarker2.setMap(map);
          bounds.extend(distmarker2.getPosition());
          DistCircle1.setOptions({
            center: distmarker.getPosition()
          });
          bounds.union(DistCircle1.getBounds());
          DistCircle2.setOptions({
            center: distmarker2.getPosition()
          });
          bounds.union(DistCircle2.getBounds());
          DistCircle1.setMap(map);
          DistCircle2.setMap(map);
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      minZoom: 9,
      maxZoom: 16,
      streetViewControl: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.077, 34.644)
        // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }
  //end of initalize
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<section>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div id="searchpanel">
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="tel aviv" />
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode" />
    <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="jerusalem" />
  </div>
</section>
```

**Side issue with the posted code**: You are including the API twice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Only include it once, include multiple libraries as a comma separated list (also the sensor parameter is no longer required, and if present should be **either** true ... or ... false):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization"></script>
```

Note: your code also doesn't use the visualization library, so that can be removed

Comment: Now its working. thanks for the help and the side notes.

Answer (score 0):

following the help by geocodezip, I'm posting the corrected code I have used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>map panel</title>

    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='img/favicon.ico'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization"></script>


    <script>    

        var map;

        //tel aviv
        var distLatLng = {lat: 32.072369, lng: 34.783513};
        //Binyamina
        var distLatLng2 = {lat: 32.521128, lng: 34.945219};

        var distmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: distLatLng});
        var distmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: distLatLng2});


        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var DistCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle({ strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', strokeOpacity: 0.9, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', fillOpacity: 0.10, map: map, center: distLatLng, radius: 30000});
        var DistCircle2 = new google.maps.Circle({ strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', strokeOpacity: 0.9, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', fillOpacity: 0.10, map: map, center: distLatLng2, radius: 30000});



        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, fn) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;


        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          fn(results[0].geometry.location); 
          } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
        })
        }

        function geocodeAddress2(geocoder, resultsMap, fn) {
        var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;


        geocoder.geocode({'address': address2}, function(results2, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          fn(results2[0].geometry.location); 
          } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
        })
        }



        function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            minZoom: 9,
            maxZoom: 16,
            streetViewControl: false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.077, 34.644),
            <!--mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE-->
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {

        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, function(location) {
        alert(location); // this is where you get the return value
        map.setCenter(location);
        distmarker.setPosition(location);
        DistCircle1.setOptions({center: distmarker.getPosition()});
        DistCircle1.setMap(map);
        });

        geocodeAddress2(geocoder, map, function(location2) {
        alert(location2); // this is where you get the return value
        distmarker2.setPosition(location2);
        DistCircle2.setOptions({center: distmarker2.getPosition()});
        DistCircle2.setMap(map);
        });




        });

        }
        //end of initalize

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>



    <section>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <div id="searchpanel">



                <input id="address" type="textbox" value="tel aviv">
                <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
                <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="jerusalem">

        </div>


    </section>

      </body>
    </html>
```